# Rails ActiveStorage fetch image from URL, then resize and upload on first hit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm building my first Rails app and I'm now at the point where I have to move the images to S3 instead of serving the hot-linked version from a third party source.

I have my models set up the following way.

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```
class Episode < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
```

## Constraints

- Every entry in the `images` table (From the Image model) has an `external_url` column
- I don't want to upload images directly when a new Episode gets created as it's too many

## What I think I want

- Use image in the templates, if image isn't yet on S3 I download the image via the URL in the  `external_url` column and put it on S3
- Resize image (via `.variants` I guess) and put resized image on S3
- Next time someone opens the page the image is served from S3 without any resizing

## Question

I see a lot of guides / tutorials / blog posts about image uploads and then uploading it to S3 but not much about doing on-demand uploads from URLs that are in the database.

What's the usual way of doing that? I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!